# Executing docker-compose.yml halts in the midway

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[image: ./two/dockerfile]
[image: error[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUqMT.png)

I tried to enter my location, but nothing happens after clicking enter.

Comment: please post here your Dockerfile

Comment: do not insert images, post code as text.